# Blazor-ApexCharts : Gradient color options does not affects on Gauge chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, apexcharts

i'm use this code to implement gauge chart (RadialBar) with custom gradient color which have to start a color and end with another color. here is my sample code :

```
ChartOptions.PlotOptions = new PlotOptions
        {
            RadialBar = new PlotOptionsRadialBar
            {
                StartAngle = -90, 
                EndAngle = 90,
                DataLabels = new RadialBarDataLabels
                {
                    Name = new RadialBarDataLabelsName 
                    { 
                        Show = false 
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    ChartOptions.Fill = new Fill
    {
        Type = new List<FillType>
        { 
            FillType.Gradient 
        },
        Gradient = new FillGradient
        {
            Shade = GradientShade.Dark, 
            Type = GradientType.Horizontal, 
            ShadeIntensity = 1, 
            GradientToColors = new List<string> { "#E966A0", "#FFB84C", "#79E0EE" },
            InverseColors = true,
            OpacityFrom = 0.7, 
            OpacityTo = 0.9,
            Stops = new List<double>{ 0, 50, 100 }
        },
    };
```

But only the first color (#E966A0) affects to my chart!!
Can anybody help me how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

**-- Edited :**

Thanks for your help
I've changed my code as follow :

```
ChartOptions.Fill = new Fill
    {
        Type = new List<FillType>
        { 
            FillType.Gradient 
        },
        Gradient = new FillGradient
        {
            Shade = GradientShade.Light, 
            Type = GradientType.Horizontal,
            ShadeIntensity = 1,
            GradientToColors = new List<string> { "#FFD95A", "#FF6969" },
            //InverseColors = true,
            OpacityFrom = 0.7, 
            OpacityTo = 0.8,
            Stops = new List<double>{ 0, 50, 100 }
        },
    };
```

ChartOptions.Colors = new List { "#1B9C85" };

Somewhat done so far. It start from Green color ('ChartOptions.Colors' property) and End with the first color of 'GradientToColors' property. But the second color of 'GradientToColors' does not affects to my chart. It's red color which i want to used that as End Color.
I want to start from Green Color, The middle of Track become Yellow color and the End Color become Red.
Can u help me how to accomplish this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The doc specifies for `gradientToColors`:

> The main colors array becomes the `gradientFromColors` and this array becomes the end colors of the gradient. Each index in the array corresponds to the series-index.

This means, if you are having only one series, you need to define `ChartOptions.Colors` being an array of one color (the beginning of the gradient) and `GradientToColors` being an array of one color as well.

If you want to add more series with different gradients, add colors in your arrays. If you have more series than colors defined, it will go back to the start of the array and loop.

**Edit**

You want the gradient to be more detailed than just a gradient between two colors. You should use `colorStops` instead, this allows you to specify exactly how you want your gradient to be. However, this option is, for now, not implemented on the Blazor version.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've set ColorStops but not affected. Can  provide a sample?

Comment: [Official doc example](https://codepen.io/apexcharts/pen/RvqdPb), for radial gauge, it follows the same logic. However, possible gradients follow a line, I did not find anything to make it circular: it might not give the exact result you are looking for.

Comment: The problem is that, documentation site is based on js frameworks (such as jquery, vue, angular, etc) and have some differences with blazor version! for example, the ColorStops property does not exists in blazor version. The blazor version just have a Stops propertye which accept List<string> variables.

Comment: You are right, this option is not implemented on the Blazor version. I don't see any better option than a gradient between two colors in that case.